# Typescript: How to indicate a property nullable by using generic

Tags: typescript

Imagine I have a type called `Person`, which for person with or without a job. If person with a job, need to provider a job details which is varying by passing `Job` generic.

Ideally, I thought this should work: `type Person<Job = undefined> = { name: string, job: Job extends undefined? never : Job  }`, but not.

I have to code like: `type People<Job = undefined> = Job extends undefined ? { name: string } : { name: string, job: Job }` to work, which is verbose.

Anyone can give a better solution? Thanks. Please check [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=10&ssc=80&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhCGBjAFhATlAvFA3lAzigPZEA2AXAcGgJYB2A5lAL4BQokUAoo-ROllxRERALZh4dEJXzV6TNh2gApIgCNBcJKgwAfbrzr80rVgHozUJVAAKEImFIQAPKo3YArnQAmEAGZ83gB8gm5QEAAewBA++FBevgFG3lAA-EJ08KIQMnKMLFCUeJnZubSMADRQAFbqlGHMUE0WUBL4+BDeVWoewFDwUKREfQBu6GpEHezg0HZo+ER0ruqCCf6BIdjFWTlU5QxVtWr1K5HRsfE+68npRmMYJxoFTS+vb82W6GhEaJSQ84sAOo0YDIIi9MKiGjteQ1FamVgiOiyVroBZ0YGg8HANyUObowTbUpQADkACVFiSCojFij-ujMchcbY0YtnFoUOhNhkdpQSQBBRgQUjwEmHOpCQhgsh80UFNhAA) or read below:

```js
type Teacher = { school: string }
type Engineer = { company: string }
type Job = Teacher | Engineer

// type People<Job = undefined> = Job extends undefined ? { name: string } : { name: string, job: Job }   // passed, but a lot verbose
type Person<Job = undefined> = { name: string, job: Job extends undefined? never : Job  }                 // error: personWithoutJob missing job 


const personWithoutJob: Person = { name: 'Ron' } 
const personWithJob: Person<Teacher> = { name: 'Angela', job: { school: 'a' } }
```

Comment: It's quite awkward to use generics for that. I'd expect `PesonWithJob extends Person` and `PersonWithoutJob extends Person` as two different interfaces.

Comment: type Person<Job> = { name?: string, job?: Job }  ?

Comment: @JohnPeters that allows for `personWithJob: Person<Teacher> = { name: "Angela" }` which shouldn't be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach is an intersection type.

Like this:

```
type Person<Job = undefined> = { name: string } & (Job extends undefined ? {} : { job: Job });
```

[updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhCGBjAFhATlAvFA3lAzigPZEA2AXAcGgJYB2A5lAL4DcAUKJFAKKP0R0WXFEREAtmHh0QlfNXpM2ncNABSRAEbC4SVBgA+vfnUFoOK7gAV0+InQA8G7dgCudACYQAZgI8A+YTw6eHEIOQVGFigAMigACmcoCAAPYAhPfCh3L19TDygAflxmKEo8ACstSiTmAEoLMTp5KEg0OzoAdRpgZCJXYGdKG3b7IKgQsMoAcgAle2mWDiaWto7u3qGoEY6HXRR0QOxg0PCoaYBBRghSeGmAGigqzXKCYjIZu+jlIA)

[official intersection types documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types)

Comment: Thanks, it is great. The `&` is great.